# How does PIE mitigate exploits?

Tags: rop, pie

I read a tutorial where they compiled with the `-no-pie` option. Is it because the `.text` segment will be loaded at a random address, therefore making the address of gadgets founds inside it useless ?

Answer (score 1):

The PIE abbreviation means "Position Independent Executable". Such an executable *may ask or not ask* the OS for the Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR), when the OS loader loads the binary and dependencies into a random location of virtual memory.

ASLR itself, *not PIE*, protects executable from *specific* malware (which rely on fixed virtual address of a particular code and tries changing it in an *already running* program). Asking for ASLR is *another* flag beside the PIE flag.

The `-no-pie` option of the GCC compiler means "no PIE" - it's only one bit in the executable header, signaling the loader that the code is position-dependent. (The loader will then load the code always into the same, fixed virtual memory location indicated in the executable's header.)